# 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute' cannot be applied to instance method

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use some winapi methods. how ever, when I try to use the function I get the following error:

> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute' cannot be applied to instance method.
>   code:

```
Public Class Anti
        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAdress As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As Integer, ByVal nSize As Integer, Optional ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer = 0) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Sub ZeroMemory(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal length As UInt32)
    End Sub
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function VirtualProtect(ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr, ByVal dwSize As Integer, ByVal flNewProtect As Integer, ByRef lpflOldProtect As UInteger) As Boolean
    End Function
    Public Sub AntiDump()
      Try
      Dim x(0) As Process
```

Comment: `Shared Function....` and if you want to keep Code Analysis happy, change the class name to `NativeMethods`

Answer (score 2):

Well, the message is pretty clear. Methods that you apply the `DllImport` attribute to must be class methods (`shared`).